# Not quite understanding a proof for a function of a random variable.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

[Theorem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ndGb.png)

[Proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5eNc.png)

Why is is that in the decreasing case in the proof, G(y) evaluates to P(X>=s(y) as opposed to P(X<=s(y)? What swaps the sense of the inequality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this says: $G(y)=\Pr(r(X) \le y)$

But if $r(x)$ is a decreasing functions, then a smaller value of $x$ corresponds to a larger value of $r(x)$ while a larger value of $x$ corresponds to a smaller value of $r(x)$.

If the inverse of $r(x)$ is $s(y)$ then this means a smaller value of $s(y)$ corresponds to a larger value of $r(s(y))=y$ while a larger value of $s(y)$ corresponds to a smaller value of $r(s(y))=y$. So $s(y)$ is also a decreasing function.

Rather like multiplying by $-1$, this means that the inequality reverses as $r(X) \le Y \iff s(r(X)) \ge s(Y) \iff X \ge s(Y)$, leading to $\Pr(r(X) \le y) = \Pr(X \ge s(y))$. That is $1-\Pr(X \lt s(y))$ but since you have a continuous distribution, it is also $1-\Pr(X \le s(y))=1-F(s(y))$ so you can say in this case $$G(y)=1-F(s(y))$$

Comment: Thank you so much for clearing this up!